# Is it possible to set the alpha property of a UITableViewCell accessoryView?

Tags: iphone

I'm using a `UIImageView` as the `accessoryView` in a `UITableViewCell` that I'm creating programmatically. I've tried everything I can think of to set the `accessoryView`'s `alpha` property, but it's not working. I'm able to set the `hidden` and `opaque` properties with no problems, but `alpha` is hating all over me.

I tried creating a new project that contains a single `UITableViewController` and the following `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = iv;
    [iv release];

    // cell.accessoryView.hidden = YES; // works
    cell.accessoryView.alpha = 0.5f;    // fails

    return cell;
}
```

As you may have guessed, the `accessoryView` is fully opaque. Am I missing something? I can't find any information about what's going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: just ran into this too after messing with it for about a half hour until i gave up. glad to see i'm not alone. :D thanks for posting the workaround. bummer though!

Comment: This is still not settable in iOS 5.1. I also tried setting the alpha of the UIImageView before setting it as the accessoryView, but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: Still the same in iOS11...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying about a billion different things and looking everywhere for some answers, I ended up just faking it by adding a subview to the cell's contentView and positioning it to the accessory position. I'm able to set the alpha property on that subview to my heart's content.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, except I baked the transparency into an image and continued to use the accessory view.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the alpha in `- (void) layoutSubviews` of a subclassed UITableViewCell by setting

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
     self.accessoryView.alpha = 0.4;
}
```

cheers

Comment: and if you want to change it in the runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do that in willDisplayCell:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.accesoryView.alpha = 0.4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I was looking for 'cell.contentView.alpha' instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can change tint color - that manipulations changes color of default accessotyView. Subclass cell and in place where colorize `BOOL _myOption` is changed add something like this:

```
self.tintColor = [self.window.tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:_myOption?1.0:0.5];
```

You can choose any other color, not only change it by alpha value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting its background color to clear color as well?
Something like this:

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you're trying to set accessoryView.alpha, you could place this code:

```
UIView *accessoryMask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.accessoryView.frame];
accessoryMask.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // or whiteColor
accessoryMask.alpha = 0.5;
accessoryMask.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:accessoryMask];
[accessoryMask release];
```

This should work well as long as your cells have a plain black or plain white background. You can set your mask to match other background colors, but then your accessoryView will be tinted.

The advantage over adding a subview to contentView is that you don't have to worry about positioning the view; the iOS will position the accessoryView as needed and your mask will follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but an approach which was for me at least working was to apply the alpha directly to the image dynamically by using this method (as category or helper in class):

```
- (UIImage *)imageByApplyingAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha toImage:(UIImage *)initialImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(initialImage.size, NO, 0.0f);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, initialImage.size.width, initialImage.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, alpha);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, initialImage.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view1 - the view you would like to add as accessory.
Create a view2 with the same size as view1. Then add view1 as subview to view2, and set the alpha of view1. Set view2 as acessoryView for the tableview cell.